# Using Generics to Multiply Collection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

> I have to write a method that takes arguments *List* and *int n*.
>
> **Method should multiply content of given *List*** in the same *List*.  If n =
>   0, than *List* shoud be empty.  If n = 1, *List* should be the same as
>   before.

For **example**:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
multiply(list, 2);
System.out.println(list);
```

---

**desired output**:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Method signature **can not be changed**:

```
public static void multiply(List<?> list, int n) {

}
```

I tried this:

```
public static void multiply(List<?> list, int n) {

        List<? super Object> copy = new ArrayList<>();

        if (n == 0) {
            list.clear();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            copy.addAll(list);         
        }

        list.clear();
        list.addAll(copy); // this is not allowed
    }
```

Thank you for advices!

Comment: Please tag this question with the `java` tag if this is about Java generics (as opposed to Kotlin, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**without changing the method signature:**

```
public static void multiply(List<?> list, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        list.clear();
        return;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object> oldSchool = (List<Object>) list;
    List<?> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        oldSchool.addAll(copy);
    }
}
```

(i had to cast list to a `List<Object>`)

**with changing the signature** (using just plain T for the generic param):

```
public static <T> void multiply(List<T> list, int n) {
    List<T> copy = new ArrayList<>();

    if (n == 0) {
        list.clear();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        copy.addAll(list);
    }

    list.clear();
    list.addAll(copy); // this is now OK
}
```

now, as for why your original code didnt compile:

`list` as essentially `List<some unknown class>`, and `copy` as `List<some PARENT of that unknown class>`

you then try to add the contents of `copy` into `list`.

this is like trying to dump the contents of a `List<Animal>` into a `List<Dog>` - they dont fit because you might have cats and crocodiles in a `List<Animal>`

Comment: the first function throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @NaorTedgi- OP used Arrays.asList(...) to create the original argument. this creates an IMMUTABLE collection. use new ArrayList() instead